# Passwordless login in drupal 7

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

If I use something like hybridauth, can I remove password field from Drupal completely? Or at the very least make it not required during registration?

Comment: `can I remove password field from Drupal completely?` then don't have users at all, or else anybody can login as Jeffrey04 and make you look bad.

Comment: I am not sure if you mean something like [oauthconnector](https://www.drupal.org/project/oauthconnector)

Comment: @NoSssweat yea, that's why I want to replace login form with modules like hybridauth... well you don't need a password to login to stackexchange sites do you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hybridauth does remove the need of password, so I probably can remove username and password fields from the user login forms through the hooks